# Problem updating joblib library from GitHub repo in IBM Watson Studio

Tags: scikit-learn, pip, joblib, data-science-experience, watson-studio

In my program, I need to use some joblib functions. However, when I run the program, I get the error message: `sklearn.externals.joblib is deprecated in 0.21 and will be removed in 0.23`.

Apparently the library has been updated in [this Github repo](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0.20.X/sklearn/externals/joblib/__init__.py) but I did not have success installing the library with the `pip install` command

I did a test just to install the setup file 
`pip install https://github.com/dsxuser/scikit-learn/setup.py/0.20.x.zip`
but i got 404 error.
What I need is to update all the joblib library in that branch.

Does anyone know how to properly install it?

Comment: How did `/dsxuser/` get into that URL?

Answer (score 3):

That's not an error, that's a warning. It tells you that you shouldn't use `sklearn.externals.joblib` anymore, if you want your code to be compatible with later versions of scikit-learn. *Should* means that you still can, as long as you do NOT upgrade scikit-learn to 0.23 or later.

The way to make your code ready for later versions of scikit-learn is to not use the [deprecated `sklearn.externals.joblib`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new.html#miscellaneous), but to [use joblib directly](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) instead. It's not pre-installed, so you can do one of these:

- `conda install joblib`
- `pip install joblib`

You didn't mention what part of Watson Studio you are using. If it's notebooks without Spark, the preferred way to install packages is with `conda`. You can define a [custom environment](https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/analyze-data/customize-envs.html) with this customization:

```
dependencies:
- joblib=0.13.2
```

or else you can call `conda` from a notebook cell:

```
!conda install joblib=0.13.2
```

If you're using some other part of Watson Studio, give `conda` a try, and if it doesn't work, switch to `pip`. Note that `pip` expects `==` instead of `=` before the version number. Specifying the version number protects you from surprises when new versions of joblib are released.